# Cordova google-map plugin not compiling

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am on cordova 4.0.0, and i want to install the phonegap google map plugin - https://github.com/wf9a5m75/phonegap-googlemaps-plugin

After proceeding the installation as explained, i have compilation problem in the `cordova build` command.

```
/home/etouraille/src/app/platforms/android/src/plugin/google/maps/GoogleMaps.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
import org.apache.cordova.ScrollEvent;
                         ^
  symbol:   class ScrollEvent
  location: package org.apache.cordova
/home/etouraille/src/app/platforms/android/src/plugin/google/maps/GoogleMaps.java:138: error: cannot find symbol
    root = (ViewGroup) webView.getParent();
                              ^
  symbol:   method getParent()
  location: variable webView of type CordovaWebView
/home/etouraille/src/app/platforms/android/src/plugin/google/maps/GoogleMaps.java:197: error: cannot find symbol
          webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
                 ^
  symbol:   method setLayerType(int,<null>)
  location: variable webView of type CordovaWebView
/home/etouraille/src/app/platforms/android/src/plugin/google/maps/GoogleMaps.java:206: error: cannot find symbol
          webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
```

I finally got the solution : look in comments, it was to dowgrade cordova while removing android platform, in the meantime cordova asked me to install android 19,and i had some solved problem with java path.

Comment: I finally get the solution, it was to downgrade cordova, first step remove android from cordova :  cordova remove platform android, then donwgrade cordova : npm install -g cordova@3.6.3-0.2.13, then install android platform cordova platform add android, and it worked like a charme !

Comment: Here, you are allowed to post an answer to your own question. So please do so, so when someone else faces the same issue, it'll be easy for them.

Answer (score 1):

It was a compatibility issue with Cordova's newer versions. Downgrading Cordova to `3.6.3` solved the issue.

Step 1: Remove `android` platform from your Cordova project:

```
 cordova platform remove android
```

Step 2: Install the compatible version of Cordova:

```
npm install -g cordova@3.6.3-0.2.13
```

Step 3: Add back the `android` platform to the Cordova project:

```
cordova platform add android
```